# jQuery unbind and bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

The case is: when I hover over a link some task should happen and when I leave the area/ mouseleave happens the hovering for the link should stay disabled for 1 second and work again.

**DEMO PLNKR:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/m6SnDzuo2MA5hoYUEoPc?p=preview

Here is **my approach**:

```
$("a").hover(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hovered');
}, function () {
    $("a").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    setTimeout(function () {
            $("a").bind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    }, 1000);       
});
```

So, whenever mouseleave event occurs, I am unbinding `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and then with a `setTimeout` and binding them again.

So, now it is unbinding fine but after a second the events are not rebinding.

Please help if I am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you bind to `hover`, and when the cursor leaves you will `unbind` `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. But you are not assigning any function to it. Do you actually want to re-assign to the previous `hover`-event?

In the example you have given you do not set a `handler`.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

> **eventType**
>
> Type: String A string containing one or more DOM event types, such as "click" or "submit," or custom event names.
>
> **handler**
>
> Type: Function( Event eventObject ) A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

```js
function onHover(){
  alert('hovered');
}

function onHoverLeft(){
  console.log('onHoverLeft called');
  $("a").off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('setTimeout is done. Will rebind hover now.');
      $("a").hover(onHover, onHoverLeft);
    }, 2000);  
}
$("a").hover(onHover, onHoverLeft);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Foo</a>
```

Comment: Yes. Actually what I wish is on mouseleave the hover event for the links should not work at all for 1second. And after that If I hover it should execute like before

Comment: thanks. did the job. but I am just unable to understand how it is rebinding in the snippet.  `$("a").off('mouseenter mouseleave');`  unbinds it. then after 1 second you are just doing the hover again.

Comment: @MarkWilson - Yes, that's right. I unbind it when it leaves the first `hover`-event. (you might want to do it _in_ the `hover`-event?). And then after 2000 milliseconds I rebind it to the initial `hover`-event with the original function.